# Java XStream Cannot Be Resolved On Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, package, xstream

I have got the XStream package by apt-get install libxstream-java. I'd like to use the XStream class in my java program, so I try to include the XStream class by importing com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream. But it does not work for me complaining the package com.thoughtworks.xstream does not exist. I have found out that the package is installed under directory: usr/share/java. Could someone please explain to me what is happening?

Comment: make sure the jar is in your class path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the Xstream.jar to your classpath. See [Setting the classpath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/classpath.html) for more details.